# Por que a classe Integer pode ser utilizada tanto para conversão do valor de objeto String para int quanto de int para String?

Tags: java, string, int

A classe *wrapper* `Integer` tem os métodos `parseInt` e `toString`.
O primeiro pode ser utilizado para converter um literal `String` em um valor `int` e o segundo para converter um valor `int` em `String`.

Se cada *wrapper* tem um equivalente primitivo, por qual razão eu uso o mesmo *wrapper* para converter um valor tipo `int` em um valor `String`?

ex:

```
String valor = "30"
idade = Integer.parseInt(valor)
```

e

```
int idade = 30
String valor = Integer.toString(idade)
```

Comment: É assim porque o tipo `int` não tem métodos, não daria pra fazer `int x = 10; String s = x.toString()`. Então decidiu-se que o *wrapper* teria o método para fazer tal conversão. Só de curiosidade, também dá pra fazer `String.valueOf(valorInteiro)`, que [segundo a documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(int)), dá o mesmo resultado de `Integer.toString`.

Comment: Sou neófito, pensei que como todo Wrapper tem um tipo primitivo de referência e para fazer a conversão usasse o Wrapper específico de cada tipo primitivo. Achei estranho que o Integer fosse usado assim. 
É simplesmente uma questão de esse wrapper ter o método que permite a conversão. É isso? Já que o wrapper String não tem tipo primitivo de referência, criaram um método parseInt para o wrapper Integer?

Comment: String não é um wrapper. Quanto ao restante, não sei se entendi exatamente a sua dúvida, mas enfim: um *wrapper* possui métodos para converter do respectivo primitivo para String e vice-versa. É assim porque decidiram fazer assim (as pessoas que definiram a linguagem acharam que fazia sentido e fizeram dessa forma)

Comment: Entendi. obrigado